# Symfony warning : spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

Tags: symfony

Hi i need to set a value but i have this error : spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

```
$I_lastIdVeilleNddHisto = 1545;
$O_v->getD()->setOldVersion($I_lastIdVeilleNddHisto);
                $this->_em->persist($O_v);
                $this->_em->flush();
```

getD is an object, and in this object i have the property oldversion, who is a string

**edit:** $o_v is in a foreach :

```
foreach ( $A_v as $O_v )...

       $A_v = $this->_O_vRepository->getForR();
```

Comment: Can you show us how `$O_v` is assigned?

Comment: hi, i add it in edit

Comment: Is it possible to change your variable name to something explicit? it will be easier for us to understand the code, and therefore to help you